# c# inheritance and ISerialize interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, interface, deserialization

I am trying to binary format a list of Animals(either a cat or a dog). This goes well to some extend. Ive made use of the ISerialize interface in my base class, Animal. The two derived classes, dog and cat, however both have 1 extra property the base class doesn't have. Now, the serialization and deserialization of the base class animal gives me no problems. The problem starts when i try to serialize and deserialize either one of those extra properties from the derived classes I mentioned earlier. I feel like there is an easy fix to this but I am overseeing something.

Below I will post code of the following locations:

1. The ISerialize interface in the Animal class
2. The ISerialize interface in the Dog class
3. The ISerialize interface in the Cat class
4. The implementation of the serializer and deserializer in the Administration class (both are bound to two buttons in a form, so i can execute them)
5. The error Visual Studio throws at me (translation of the dutch text: "Member BadHabits is not found")

I thank you in advance for any remarks and/or solutions to this problem.

```
[Serializable()]
abstract public class Animal : ISellable, IComparable<Animal>, ISerializable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The chipnumber of the animal. Must be unique. Must be zero or greater than zero.
    /// </summary>
    public int ChipRegistrationNumber { get; private set; }
    public abstract decimal Price { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date of birth of the animal.
    /// </summary>
    public SimpleDate DateOfBirth { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the animal.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is the animal reserved by a future owner yes or no.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsReserved { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an animal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chipRegistrationNumber">The chipnumber of the animal. 
    ///                                      Must be unique. Must be zero or greater than zero.</param>
    /// <param name="dateOfBirth">The date of birth of the animal.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the animal.</param>
    public Animal(int chipRegistrationNumber, SimpleDate dateOfBirth, string name)
    {
        if (chipRegistrationNumber < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Chipnummer moet groter of gelijk zijn aan 0");
        }

        ChipRegistrationNumber = chipRegistrationNumber;

        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Naam is null");
        }

        Name = name;
        IsReserved = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve information about this animal
    /// 
    /// Note: Every class inherits (automagically) from the 'Object' class,
    /// which contains the virtual ToString() method which you can override.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string containing the information of this animal.
    ///          The format of the returned string is
    ///          "<ChipRegistrationNumber>, <DateOfBirth>, <Name>, <IsReserved>"
    ///          Where: IsReserved will be "reserved" if reserved or "not reserved" otherwise. 
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string IsReservedString;

        if (IsReserved)
        {
            IsReservedString = "reserved";
        }
        else
        {
            IsReservedString = "not reserved";
        }

        string info = ChipRegistrationNumber
                      + ", " + DateOfBirth
                      + ", " + Name
                      + ", " + IsReservedString;
        return info;
    }

    private Animal(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        ChipRegistrationNumber = (Int32)info.GetValue("Chipnumber", typeof(Int32));
        DateOfBirth = (SimpleDate)info.GetValue("Date of Birth", typeof(SimpleDate));
        Name = (String)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(String));
        IsReserved = (bool)info.GetValue("Isreserved", typeof(bool));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Chipnumber", ChipRegistrationNumber);
        info.AddValue("Date of Birth", DateOfBirth);
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("Isreserved", IsReserved);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Animal other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

dog

```
[Serializable]
public class Dog : Animal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The date of the last walk of the dog. Contains null if unknown.
    /// </summary>
    public SimpleDate LastWalkDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a dog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chipRegistrationNumber">The chipnumber of the animal. 
    ///                                      Must be unique. Must be zero or greater than zero.</param>
    /// <param name="dateOfBirth">The date of birth of the animal.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the animal.</param>
    /// <param name="lastWalkDate">The date of the last walk with the dog or null if unknown.</param>
    public Dog(int chipRegistrationNumber, SimpleDate dateOfBirth,
               string name, SimpleDate lastWalkDate) : base(chipRegistrationNumber, dateOfBirth, name)
    {
        if (lastWalkDate != null)
        {
            this.LastWalkDate = lastWalkDate;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve information about this dog
    /// 
    /// Note: Every class inherits (automagically) from the 'Object' class,
    /// which contains the virtual ToString() method which you can override.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string containing the information of this animal.
    ///          The format of the returned string is
    ///          "Dog: <ChipRegistrationNumber>, <DateOfBirth>, <Name>, <IsReserved>, <LastWalkDate>"
    ///          Where: IsReserved will be "reserved" if reserved or "not reserved" otherwise.
    ///                 LastWalkDate will be "unknown" if unknown or the date of the last doggywalk otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // TODO: Put your own code here to make the method return the string specified in the
        // method description.
        if (LastWalkDate == null)
        {
            return $"Dog: {base.ToString()} - unknown";
        }
        return $"Dog: {base.ToString()}, {LastWalkDate}";
    }

    public override decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            if(ChipRegistrationNumber < 50000)
            {
                return 200;
            }

            return 350;
        }
    }

    public new void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Lastwalk", LastWalkDate);
    }

    public Dog(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        LastWalkDate = (SimpleDate)info.GetValue("Lastwalk", typeof(SimpleDate));
    }
}
```

cat

```
[Serializable]
public class Cat : Animal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the bad habits that the cat has (e.g. "Scratches the couch").
    /// or null if the cat has no bad habits.
    /// </summary>
    public string BadHabits { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a cat.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chipRegistrationNumber">The chipnumber of the animal. 
    ///                                      Must be unique. Must be zero or greater than zero.</param>
    /// <param name="dateOfBirth">The date of birth of the animal.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the animal.</param>
    /// <param name="badHabits">The bad habbits of the cat (e.g. "scratches the couch")
    ///                         or null if none.</param>
    public Cat(int chipRegistrationNumber, SimpleDate dateOfBirth,
               string name, string badHabits) : base(chipRegistrationNumber, dateOfBirth, name)
    {
        this.BadHabits = badHabits;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve information about this cat
    /// 
    /// Note: Every class inherits (automagically) from the 'Object' class,
    /// which contains the virtual ToString() method which you can override.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string containing the information of this animal.
    ///          The format of the returned string is
    ///          "Cat: <ChipRegistrationNumber>, <DateOfBirth>, <Name>, <IsReserved>, <BadHabits>"
    ///          Where: IsReserved will be "reserved" if reserved or "not reserved" otherwise.
    ///                 BadHabits will be "none" if the cat has no bad habits, or the bad habits string otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // TODO: Put your own code here to make the method return the string specified in the
        // method description.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(BadHabits))
        {
            BadHabits = "none";
        }

        return $"{"Cat: "}{base.ToString()}, {BadHabits}";
    }

    public override decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            int korting = BadHabits.Length - 60;
            if ( korting > 20)
            {
                return korting;
            }

            return 20;
        }
    }

    public new void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("BadHabits", this.BadHabits);
    }
    public Cat(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        this.BadHabits = (String)info.GetString("BadHabits");
    }
}
```

Administration

```
    public void Save(String fileName)
    {
        Stream fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
        format.Serialize(fileStream, Animals);
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    public void Load(String fileName)
    {
        FileStream fileStream;
        BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
        fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        Animals = (List<Animal>)format.Deserialize(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucezQ.png)

Comment: Can you post the Dog and Cat Classes as well?

Comment: [Why not upload image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1997232)?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do here? importantly: `ISerializable`, `BinaryFormatter`, et al - should be considered **obsolete and actively dangerous**, so if you're not absolutely 100% tied to `BinaryFormatter`: *any other seiralizer would be a huge improvement*. If you can clarify why you're using `BinaryFormatter` specifically, we may be able to advise more.

Comment: Unrelated: `if (name == null)` you may want to consider using `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(string)`.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, i oversighted that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "new" part in your child method. By writing "new" on child class, implementation of inherited methods are going to be hidden.

Constructors are written properly, methods are the problem.

Here is one way you can fix this:

```
class Animal
{
   ...
   public virtual GetObjectData(... params ...)
   {
     // populate properties
   }
   ...
}

class Dog
{
    public override GetObjectData(... params ...)
    {
      base.GetObjectData(... params ...)
      // populate additional Dog properties
    }
}
```